# ND4J, multidimensional matrix transpose with axes

Tags: nd4j

What is the `NDArray` equivalent for numpy transpose like this: `out = np.transpose(in, (0,2,1,3))`?
(`in` is of rank 4)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the [INDArray.permute(dimension rages)](https://nd4j.org/doc/org/nd4j/linalg/api/ndarray/INDArray.html#permute-int...-) does exactly what i've been looking for.

The ND4J's `outNDArray = inNDArray.permute(0,2,1,3)` is equivalent to NumPy's `out = np.transpose(in, (0,2,1,3))`

Comment: Glad to know that you've found out the solution ;)